# c# регулярное выражение

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Как правильно составить регулярку для удаления всех символов кроме тех которые в скобках.
Есть строка:

```
string text = "Hello 15s (Text 1). Are";
```

Должно остаться:

```
string text = "Text 1";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

как-то так:

```
[(].*[)]
```

..................................................................

Comment: Regex.Replace(fileName, "[(].*[)]", ""); Так будет удалено все внутри скобок, а нужно наоборот.

Comment: так не используй риплейс, используй матч.